# Where are forwarding rules found on the GCE console?

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine

Title says it all: Where are network forwarding rules to be found on the GCE console (GUI)? I searched the Networking area and could not find them. The Google documentation also does not mention this. Is the command-line interface really the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Cloud console->Networking->Load Balancing page click "advanced menu" at the bottom. The new page will have the tab for Forwarding rules as well as Global forwarding rules.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect to find this under Load Balancing. I used to accomplish what I want to do with IPTABLES and DNAT, so this load balancing thing seems like overkill to me, but that'll be a differrent question ;-)